# Vaadin with JQuery FileUpload

Tags: file-upload, vaadin, image-uploading, jquery-file-upload, vaadin7

I would like to create *FileUploader*  with **Vaadin** . But I need to get more features over [normal Vaadin Upload](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/other/upload).

1. beautiful and easy to manage (but optional)
2. fast and never failed while uploading
3. include progress bar
4. show preview
5. multi file upload support
6. upload file size and type restriction
7. drag and drop
8. client-side image resizable *(it is main feature for me because all of my uploaded files were images)*

There has an addon [MultiFileUpload](https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/multifileupload). Yes , it is perfect for most of my requirements but not for **client-size image resizing**. So I decided to use [JQuery FileUpload](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) because it is support for [Client side Image Resizing](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing).

I used vaadin [Window](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Window.html) for upload image. But I got a problem while creating my window , very hard to create each HTML elements respectively (*may be I have less exp*). So I used [CustomLayout with HTML](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/layout.customlayout.html) for easy to create and edit  design of my image uploader window.

Below is my custom layout HTML file. (*two scripts were templates for image preview*)

```
<script id="template-upload" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-upload">
    <td width="100px" align="center">
        <span class="preview"></span>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" align="center">
        <p class="name">{%=file.name%}</p>
        {% if (!o.files.error) { %}
            <div class="progress progress-success progress-striped active" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="0"><div class="bar" style="width:0%;"></div></div>
        {% } %}
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <div><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
        {% } %}
    </td>
    <td width="100px" align="center">
        {% if (!i) { %}
            <button style="display: none;" class="start" type="button">
                <span>Start</span>
            </button>
            <div class="v-button v-widget cancel" type = "button">
                <span class="v-button-wrap" style="color: red;">
                    <span class="v-button-caption">Cancel</span>
                </span>
            </div>
        {% } %}
        <br>
        {%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}
    </td>
</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<!-- The template to display files available for download -->
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
<tr class="template-download">
    <td width="100px" align="center">
        <span class="preview">
            {% if (file.path) { %}
                <img src="../{%=file.path%}" width="100px">
            {% } %}
        </span>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" align="center">
        <p class="name">
            {%=file.name%}
        </p>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <div><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
        {% } %}
    </td>
    <td width="100px" align="center">
        <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
<table cellpadding="5" style="width: 100%;">
<colgroup>
<col>
</colgroup>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="90px">
            <div style="text-align: right; width: 120px;">UploadPhoto :</div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="pnlProgress" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" style="display: none;" class="progress progressall progress-success progress-striped active">
                <div style="width: 0%;" class="allbar" id="pnlProgressBar">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div id="imageForm" style="width: 600px;">
                <form id="fileupload">
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px; border: 1px solid #DDD; width: 600px; height: 300px; overflow: scroll">
                        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5">
                            <tbody class="files"></tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;" class="fileupload-buttonbar">
                        <div class="v-button v-widget btnPlus">
                            <span class="v-button-caption">Add Files</span> 
                            <input type="file" multiple="" name="files[]">
                        </div>
                        <div class="v-button v-widget start" type = "submit">
                            <span class="v-button-wrap">
                                <span class="v-button-caption">StartUpload</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="v-button v-widget cancel" type = "reset">
                            <span class="v-button-wrap">
                                <span class="v-button-caption">Cancel All</span>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid #999; width: 600px; height: 100px;" id="dropZone">
                        <div class="carPhotoDropMsg">
                            Draft &amp; Drop Photos<br>(jpg, jpeg, png, gif only)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Below is for ImageUpload window

```
public final class ImageUploadDialog extends CustomComponent {
private Window window;

public void show() {
    UI.getCurrent().addWindow(window);
 // 123 is seq for save in database or other use
    Page.getCurrent().getJavaScript().execute("initImageuploader(123)");
}

public ImageUploadDialog() {
    CustomLayout layout = new CustomLayout("imageUploadLayout");
    window = new Window("Uploading Photos");
    window.center();
    window.setWidth("615px");
    window.setModal(true);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setClosable(true);
    window.setContent(layout);
}
}
```

And below is my upload.js file for initialize my image uploader

```
function initImageuploader(seq) {
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url : 'photo/upload.html?s=' + seq,
    sequentialUploads : true,
    disableImageResize : false,
    imageMaxWidth : 1024,
    imageMaxHeight : 1024,
    previewCrop : true,
    dropZone : $("#dropZone"),
    acceptFileTypes : /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    progress : function(e, data) {
        if (data.context) {
            var progress = data.loaded / data.total * 100;
            progress = Math.floor(progress);
            $('.progress').attr('aria-valuenow', progress);
            $('.progress').css('display', 'block');
            $('.bar').css('width', progress + '%');
        }
    },
    progressall : function(e, data) {
        var progress = data.loaded / data.total * 100;
        progress = Math.floor(progress);
        $('.progressall').attr('aria-valuenow', progress);
        $('.progressall').css('display', 'block');
        $('.allbar').css('width', progress + '%');
        if (progress > 20) {
            $('.allbar').text(progress + '% Completed');
        }
    },
    stop: function (e) {
        return;
    }
});
}
```

And you need additional javascripts files for image uploader and I imported them at my UI class as below

```
@JavaScript({ "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/load-image.min.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/tmpl.min.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/jquery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/jquery/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/jquery/jquery.iframe-transport.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/jquery/jquery.fileupload.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/jquery/jquery.fileupload-ui.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/jquery/jquery.fileupload-process.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/jquery/jquery.fileupload-image.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/jquery/jquery.fileupload-validate.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/canvas-to-blob.min.js",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/js/upload.js" })
@StyleSheet({ "vaadin://themes/myproject/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css",
    "vaadin://themes/myproject/css/imageUpload.css" })
public class EntryPoint extends UI {
..............
}
```

> **Please Notice for JS Files Order !**

Below is my Custom CSS file for image upload window (*imageUpload.css*)

```
table.upld-status {
display: none;
}
.fileupload-buttonbar .btnPlus {
float: left;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
color: blue;
text-align: center;
margin-right : 10px;
}
.fileupload-buttonbar .btnPlus input {
margin: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
line-height: 30px;
font-size: 23px;
direction: ltr;
opacity: 0;
}
.carPhotoDropMsg {
color: #DDD;
font-size: 20pt;
height: 82%;
padding: 9px;
text-align: center;
}
.progress {
background-color: #F7F7F7;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F5F5F5, #F9F9F9);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset;
height: 17px;
overflow: hidden;
}
.progress-success.progress-striped .bar, .progress-success.progress-striped .allbar, .progress
striped .bar-success {
background-color: #62C462;
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
}
.progress.active .bar, .progress.active .allbar {
animation: 2s linear 0s normal none infinite progress-bar-stripes;
}
.progress-success .bar, .progress-success .allbar, .progress .bar-success {
background-color: #5EB95E;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #62C462, #57A957);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
.progress-striped .bar, .progress-striped .allbar {
background-color: #149BDF;
background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
background-size: 40px 40px;
}
.progress .bar, .progress .allbar {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
background-color: #0E90D2;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #149BDF, #0480BE);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
color: #FFFFFF;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
height: 100%;
text-align: center;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
transition: width 0.4s ease 0s;
width: 0;
}
```

I need server-side control for save image . You need two jars [apache-common-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) and [apache-common-fileupload](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.3). Below is for maven repository of these two jars.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Finally , below is codes for server-side control .

```
@WebServlet(value = "/photo/upload.html")
public class UploadServletController extends HttpServlet {
protected final void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> fields = null;
    try {
        fields = upload.parseRequest(request);
    }
    catch (FileUploadException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Error Parsing File Item " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    if (fields != null) {
        String message = uploadPhoto(request, fields);
        out.write(message);
    }
}
public final synchronized String uploadPhoto(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final List<FileItem> sessionFiles) {

    List<Map<String, Object>> ret = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
    for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
        if (!item.isFormField()) {
            Long seq = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("s"));
// get from vm arguments (eg:-DstaticDir=/Applications/springsource/workspace/myproject/src/main/webapp)
            String staticDir = System.getProperty("staticDir");

            Date today = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat fmtYMD = new SimpleDateFormat("/yyyyMMdd/HH");
            SimpleDateFormat fmtHMS = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmssS");

            String saveDir = "data/photo" + fmtYMD.format(today);
            String format = ".jpg";
            try {
                format = item.getName().substring(item.getName().lastIndexOf("."), item.getName().length())
                        .toLowerCase();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing to do!
            }

            String fileName = seq + "_" + fmtHMS.format(today) + format;
            Map<String, Object> res = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            // Save image in specify location
            String filePath = staticDir + "/" + saveDir;
            saveFile(filePath, fileName, item);

            res.put("seq", seq);
            res.put("path", saveDir + "/" + fileName);
            res.put("ext", format.substring(1));

            res.put("name", item.getName());
            res.put("size", item.getSize());
            ret.add(res);
        }
    }
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    result.put("files", ret);
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);

    return obj.toString();
}
public static String saveFile(final String filePath, final String fileName, final FileItem item) {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdirs();
    }
    File imageFile = new File(file, fileName);
    try {
        item.write(imageFile);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    item.setFieldName(filePath + fileName);
    return item.toString();
}
}
```

I know my codes may have risks and some weakpoints . Every suggestions were welcome . But I believe there has some useful for newbie (*I am also a newbie*). Sorry for too long and bad format.

The last thing is my problem ....

Why preview image (*after upload not before upload*) automatically include **url** instead of filepath ? I got image not found error

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/myproject/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/data/photo/20140723/23/123_235918346.jpg"
```

Actually this image path should be `data/photo/20140723/23/111_235918346.jpg`. I have no idea why prefix url `http://localhost:8080/myproject/VAADIN/themes/myTheme/` was automatically include (*may be due to my CustomLayout HTML file path*) ? File paths were got from HTTP response (with JSON). I think it is due to VAADIN because it works on my GWT project or may be I am wrong. Any suggestions ? Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: Nice work! You should make an addon from it.

Comment: @adam0404 I am glad for your message but I have still less exp on vaadin . I can say I am totally a newbie . I don't know how to create addons. Thanks.

Comment: It's not that hard. You put your code into a single jar, make some properties customizable and then read this https://vaadin.com/directory/help/creating-vaadin-add-ons.

Comment: @adam0404 Thanks for useful knowledges and link . I really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by repairing **src** value of preview template for after upload image as ...

```
<script id="template-download" type="text/x-tmpl">
{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) {; %}
<tr class="template-download">
    <td width="100px" align="center">
        <span class="preview">
            {% if (file.path) { %}
                <img src="/myproject/{%=file.path%}" width="100px">
            {% } %}
        </span>
    </td>
    <td width="400px" align="center">
        <p class="name">
            {%=file.name%}
        </p>
        {% if (file.error) { %}
            <div><span class="label label-important">Error</span> {%=file.error%}</div>
        {% } %}
    </td>
    <td width="100px" align="center">
        <span class="size">{%=o.formatFileSize(file.size)%}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
{% } %}
</script>
```

Now everythings were fine. If you didn't see image immidiately , please check your IDE (Eclipse or STS) setting as below

> ***Preference > General > Workspace***

and check checkboxes `Refresh on access` and `Refresh using native hooks or polling`.