# JS and Vaadin upload component

Tags: javascript, vaadin

Do you have any ideas how I may to connect from javascript to vaadin upload component and read file name (choosen):

(from firebug):

```
<input class="gwt-FileUpload" type="file" name="503_file">
```

after refreshing site value of name has different value...

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885689/vaadin-with-jquery-fileupload

Comment: resolved :) new version of vaadin has: https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/ui/Upload.ChangeEvent.html