# How to create a custom vaadin component in vaadin 6

Tags: jquery, html, css, vaadin

I searched it a lot but could not able to find any documentation that exactly defines my problem. I want to have a simple vaadin component that has

```
 <div id="click">Click Me</div>
```

Through jQuery, on click event, it show me alert box that says "Hello my custom vaadin6 component" and also it has yellow as background-color.

In this way i will come to know following by this exercise.
1- How to attach javascript file (jQuery lib).
2- How to use HTML/CSS layout.
Thank you

Comment: Why don't you try to search in google first ? There has many links .... [Have some useful tips for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885689/vaadin-with-jquery-fileupload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should start with a simple component and then later add jQuery support to it.

In the book of vaadin 6 there is a chapter about component development

https://vaadin.com/book/vaadin6/-/page/gwt.html

For more inspiration you can look a the source of existing vaadin addons.

The dcharts widget for example also uses jQuery

https://vaadin.com/directory#addon/dcharts-widget:vaadin=6