# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload not displaying thumbnail after uploading the image

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

I have downloaded **latest** plugin and dependencies from [here](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/tags) version  9.12.1.

I copied the downloaded files in my wamp server and accessed it from *localhost/jQuery-File-Upload-9.12.1/index.html*.

After selecting image file, a preview of image is displayed before uploading. But once image is uploaded the thumbnail is not getting displayed.

However in *Inspect Element* the link of thumbnail is present in image src.

[image]

File is uploaded in server folder and thumbnail is created.

[image]

Name and size of image is getting displayed.
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Please, Can you share path of inspect element link of thumbnail. and please verify with path image is there or not

Comment: @AshokChitroda, I have edited the question.

Comment: If I delete .htaccess file then it works. Why is it so ?

Comment: I also faced this problem for a long time. When I inspect with developer plugins .. this image is loaded and also succefully loaded to my directory. I amusing eclipse IDE and already set "Refresh on access". Has somebody experience with this problem ?

Comment: It is work with Vaadin. Please check my full code [Vaadin with JQuery FileUpload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885689/vaadin-with-jquery-fileupload) but .... now I am testing in struts2+JSP ... I got the exactly error as OP.

Comment: Can you show me log error from console of browser ??

Comment: @HoangHieu error is just simple 404. The problem is writing image is a little late than response to client. So , 404 error for this image after rendering to html. But image is actually exist when I checked. As my answer .... I am trying to wait for loading image after server has successfully created image. I know it is not a good way but it works. I believe this error will not happen at production mode and I am trying to fix for running at localhost.

Comment: Can you send me sample code php and javascript :)... let me check :).

Comment: What's the content of the .htacces file?

Answer (score 0):

Making with dirty tricks ... loop until the image is ready before showing preview image. 

See [jQuery: Check if image exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327655/jquery-check-if-image-exists#answer-9377204). In my case I use before the image tag as ...

```
            while(urlExists(file.path) != 200) {
                   console.log("still loading image");
            }
            <img src="=file.path" width="100px">
```

The problem is writing image is a little late than response to client. So , 404 error for this image after rendering to html. But image is actually exist when I checked. As above snippet ,I am trying to wait for loading image after server has successfully created image. I know it is not a good way but it works. I believe this error will not happen at production mode and I am trying to fix for running at localhost.

Answer (score 0):

As per your question and comments, check for two things:

First, the thumbnail image downloaded has status 200 or 404 in network tab of developer window. If its 200, issue is something else.

If it is 404:
Check in your `.htaccess` file for this content:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|css)$ - [F]
```

> The above lines tell the Apache Web Server to block all links to
>   '.gif', '.jpg' and '.css' files which are not from the domain name
>   'http://www.yourdomain.com/'. Before uploading your .htaccess file
>   ensure you replace 'yourdomain.com' with the appropriate web site
>   address.

See if the url in .htaccess is properly set to your domain (i.e., localhost).

Reference: http://www.htaccess-guide.com/hot-link-prevention-techniques/